# How to insert from clipboard to input with IMACROS?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, imacros

My code:

```
    SET !VAR1 {{!CLIPBOARD}}
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:champ ATTR=ID:url CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Nothing appears in input, but if i set VAR1 with some string the insertion is correct

```
    SET !VAR1 some-string
    TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:champ ATTR=ID:url CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: FCI not mentioned (check my Profile on how to ask Qt's about iMacros "a bit correctly"...), but you possibly have some (Soft) Return(s) or Tab(s) or any "special" Chars in your Clipboard that are not accepted by this `INPUT` Field, check the Content of your Clipboard with `PROMPT Content_Clipboard:<SP>_{{!CLIPBOARD}}_`... :idea: // The x2 "_" Chars around the Var are meant to display any such Chars/Spacing/Returns...

Comment: + Comment I wanted to add yesterday but the Site went into maintenance...: "Only "FF" (= 'Firefox') mentioned about your FCI but if you are using v8.9.7 for FF, another "Option" would be to use `Ctrl^v` (= Paste) with the `EVENT` Mode (+ `MODIFIERS` Param). (But the `EVENT` Mode is not supported in v10.0.x for FF, or not "yet" at least...) But the `!CLIPBOARD` Command should work for all Versions..."